# Apps Script - For loop is slow. How to make it faster?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My spreadsheet has a column (A) with over 1000 rows of values like 10.99€, 25.99 € and so on. for optimizing purposes, I am looping through this column and removing the "EUR" mark and replacing "." with ",". While the code works, my problem is that it takes super long to execute and for thousands of products it sometimes time outs. I know I am probably not following the best practices, but this was the best solution I could come up with because of my limited JavaScript skills. Any help?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Table');
  var lastRow = sheet.getRange(1,1).getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS).getLastRow();
  for (var i = 1; i < lastRow +1; i++) {
    var price = sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue();
    var removeCur = price.toString().replace(" EUR","").replace(".",",");
    sheet.getRange(i,1).setValue(removeCur);
  }
}
```

Comment: You have a an API call in every `for` loop iteration, that indeed is slow. What you need to do is get your range values, run `map()` through every value and then paste the new array into your spreadsheet __once__. There is more on best practices on [Google Developers here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) if you like.

Comment: I see no accepted answer. Why? Are you waiting another correct answer?

Comment: Yuri, thank you for a brilliant answer. Marked it correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a classic question. Classic answer -- you need to replace `cell.getValue()` with `range.getValues()`. To get this way 2D-array. Process the array with a loop (or map, etc). And then set all values of the array at once back on sheet with `range.setValues()`

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices?hl=en

For this case it could be something like this:

```
function main() {
  var ss    = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Table');
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data  = range.getValues(); // get a 2d array

  // process the array (make changes in first column)
  const changes = x => x.toString().replace(" EUR","").replace(".",",");
  data = data.map(x => [changes(x[0])].concat(x.slice(1,)));

  range.setValues(data);  // set the 2d array back to the sheet
}
```

Just in case here is the same code with loop `for`:

```
function main() {
  var ss    = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Table');
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data  = range.getValues();

  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    data[i][0] = data[i][0].toString().replace(" EUR","").replace(".",",")
  }
  
  range.setValues(data);  
}
```

Probably the loop `for` looks cleaner in this case than `map`.

And if you sure that all changes will be in column A you can make the script even faster if you change third line in the function this way:

```
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
```

It will narrow the range to one column.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's something you can do to improve your code, can't guarantee it will help you to make it faster, but we'll see.

Here's the updated version

```
function myFunction() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Table');
   var lastRow = sheet.getRange(1,1).getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS).getLastRow() + 1;
   var price;
   var removeCur;
   for (var i = 1; i < lastRow; i++) {
       price = sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue();
       removeCur = price.toString().replace(" EUR","").replace(".",",");
       sheet.getRange(i,1).setValue(removeCur);
   }
}
```

What I did:

1. **Line 5**: I removed the +1 in the loop and added on lastRow directly. If you have 1000 rows, you'll save 1000 assignments
2. **Line 6-7**: removed declarations in the loop. If you have 1000 rows, you'll save 2000 re-declarations (not sure if it does, but it's best practise anyway)

You could use regex for the replace, so you do it only once, but I think it's slower, so I kept the 2 replaces there

Comment: Thank you for your answer and improvements. Unfortunately its still running as slow as before.